# Is it possible to add a method call to a property that is not a class/object?

Tags: c#

My class has a property that looks like this:

```
public string DueDateAsString
{
    get 
    {
        DateTime duedate = this.RigActionType.FrequencyType.GetDueDateForAction(this);
        if (this.HasBeenCompleted(duedate))
        {
            return "Completed";
        }
        else if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Today, duedate) > 0) // past due
        {
            return duedate.ToString() + " (past due)";
        }

        return duedate.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would like to extend the functionality a bit more so that this could also return something like "due in n days" but in a way that I don't have to create a separate property called `VerboseDueDateAsString` (or something).

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
someObject.DueDateAsString; // Outputs "4/1/2014"
someObject.DueDateAsString.Verbose; // Outputs "Due in x days"
```

Comment: It could be, if you'd return custom class instead of `string`, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could expose the due date as a property and create an extension method for the conversion. Place it in a static class whose namespace is visible where you need it.

```
public static string Verbose(this DateTime date)
{
    return String.Format("Due in {0} days", (DateTime.Now - date).Days);
}
```

Then apply it directly to the due date

```
Console.WriteLine(someObject.DueDate.Verbose());
```

---

If you replace your actual property with a similar exetension method you will get a consitent way of displaying due dates

```
public static string Concise(this DateTime date)
{
    // Place the logic of DueDateAsString here
}
```

```
Console.WriteLine(someObject.DueDate.Concise());
```

Answer (score 1):

`DueDateAsString` doesn’t really seem like it should be a property in the first place.

```
struct DueDate {
    DateTime date;
    bool completed;

    public DueDate(DateTime date, bool completed) {
        this.date = date;
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        if (this.completed) {
            return "Completed";
        }

        if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Today, duedate) > 0) // past due
        {
            return duedate.ToString() + " (past due)";
        }

        return duedate.ToString();
    }

    public string ToVerboseString() {
        // Implement this
    }
}
⋮
public DueDate DueDate
{
    get 
    {
        DateTime duedate = this.RigActionType.FrequencyType.GetDueDateForAction(this);

        return new DueDate(duedate, this.HasBeenCompleted(duedate));
    }
}
```

You *could* use an extension method on `DateTime`, but then there’s still the matter of determining whether it’s completed or not.

Name it something other than `DueDate`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`DueDateAsString` would need to be an object that itself contains a `Verbose` method afaik